# Porque é que retorna sempre null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Criei [este FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/epgq0qj1/1/) como teste.

Tenho esta `li` dentro de uma variável e pretendo adicionar a classe `c2` a essa mesma `li`

```
var linha = '<li id= "id1" class="c1"> ' + 
            '<div id="id2">1</div>' +
            '<div id="id3">2</div></li>'

document.getElementById('id1').addClass('c2');
```

O meu problema é que o `document.getElementById('id1')` dá-me sempre **NULL** e depois quando tento adicionar a classe dá-me o erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Retorna `null` porque  o `li` está apenas numa variável e não no DOM.

Comment: @Earendul existe alguma maneira para apanhar a `li` estando essa numa variavel?

Comment: onde entra o jquery nisso?

Comment: por quê então não modifica diretamente na variável ?

Comment: examplo:  linha = '<li id= "id1" class="c2"> ' +

Comment: porque isto foi um pequeno exemplo para exemplificar o meu problema

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estás a misturar elementos nativos com métodos do jQuery. O `document.getElementById('id1')` dá `null` porque no `document` (i.e. a página) não existe nenhum elemento com id `id1`. Ele existe somente dentro da *string* `linha`.

Se queres usar o `addClass` tens de selecionar o elemento com jQuery assim:

```
var linha = '<li id= "id1" class="c1"> ' +
    '<div id="id2">1</div>' +
    '<div id="id3">2</div></li>'
var $linha = $(linha);
$linha.addClass('c2');
$(document.body).append($linha); // ou dentro do <ul> que imagino que tenhas
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9p37Lff1/

Podes criar uma `div` temporária para fazer mudanças dessas. Se usares métodos nativos podes usar o `classList` assim:

```
var linha = '<li id= "id1" class="c1"> ' +
    '<div id="id2">1</div>' +
    '<div id="id3">2</div></li>'
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = linha;
temp.querySelector('#id1').classList.add('c2');
document.body.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML;
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9p37Lff1/1/

Comment: Estou a tentar fazer com o 1º exemplo que me proporcionaste. Assim quando eu atribuo a `class c2` eu atribuo-o à `var`. Não o consigo atribuir tendo em conta o `id` da `li`?

Comment: @msm.oliveira no primeiro exemplo `$linha` é o próprio elemento `li`, dentro de um objeto do jQuery. Não precisas selecionar nada... Acho que precisas mostrar mais código do que estás a fazer. Usa o meu jsFiddle e completa-o para mostrar o teu problema, senão vai ser dificil perceber o que te está a falhar, pois como vês no jsFiddle funciona bem.

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema. A sua solução ajudou bastante. Vou aceitar como resposta

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que sua variável `linha` não está adicionada ao `document` para que você possa fazer a seleção através de `document.getElementById('id1')`, então para resolver isso sem a utilização de jQuery, você deve adicionar a variável `linha` a um [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), no caso pode ser um DOM virtual:

```js
var linha = '<li id= "id1" class="c1"> ' +
  '<div id="id2">1</div>' +
  '<div id="id3">2</div></li>';

// cria dom virtual
var domVirtual = document.createElement("span");
// adicionar string html ao domVirtual, tornado-a um elemento html de fato
domVirtual.innerHTML = linha;
// seleciona elemento no dom virtual por id
var id1 = domVirtual.querySelector("#id1");
// adiciona class ao elemento
id1.classList.add("c2");

console.log(id1.className)

// agora aqui sua variavel id1, já está com o elemento pronto para ser utilizado.
```

[Exemplo jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/epgq0qj1/3/)

Outro problema em seu código é que não há o método `addClass` na [interface Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), onde você pode utilizar para essa finalidade o método [`classList` (que é *readonly*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), utilizando então o método `add()` do `classList`, sendo representado por essa parte do código apresentado anteriormente:

```
// adiciona class ao elemento
id1.classList.add("c2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @Sergio, não precisa selecionar por id pois quando você passa uma string com html para o jquery, como está a utilizar, o mesmo mantém como seleção todos os elementos `root` (no caso, apenas a li que você deseja).

Caso você tenha mais li's na string, pode utilizar o método `filter`, ou ainda, se o que você quer está em elementos de nível mais baixo, pode utilizar o `find`.

```
var $linha = $("<li id='id1'>li a ser selecionada</li>" +
               "<li id='id2'>li não selecionada</li>");
$linha.filter("#id1").addClass("c2");
```

---

```
var $linha = $("<div id='container'>" +
                   "<li id='id1'>li a ser selecionada</li>" +
                   "<li id='id2'>li não selecionada</li>" +
               "</div>");
$linha.find("#id1").addClass("c2");
```